# Simulating a submit button through jquery and collecting all html input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I have the following form:

```
<form method="post">
  <div class="summary">
    <div class="trip">
      <select name="State" class="state">
        <option selected disabled>Choose a State</option>
        <option value="1">California</option>
        <option value="2">New York</option>
      </select>
      <select name="State" class="state">
        <option selected disabled>Choose a State</option>
        <option value="1">California</option>
        <option value="2">New York</option>
      </select>
      ...
      Repeated an unknown number of times.
      ...
      <br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="calculate">
 </form>
```

I would like to simulate the calculate button as a submit button with jquery using an ajax call.

In a regular submit within Django/html, the post request would collect and send a list of the 'state' values (given there are multiple selections with the name 'state') and other input values to the server.

Is there a similar function in jquery that collect all of the input value from the html to include as an argument for the ajax call??

Comment: You mean like serialize?
https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: You can use serialize functionality.

Comment: What is expected result of multiple `<select>` elements which have same `name` attribute value within `<form>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery has a `serialize` function

```
var postData =$('form').serialize();
```

This will serialize your form into the same string that would be posted to your server.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <div class="summary">
    <div class="trip">
      <input name="city" value="Some City" type="text" />
      <select name="State" class="state">
        <option selected disabled>Choose a State</option>
        <option value="1">California</option>
        <option value="2">New York</option>
      </select>
      <select name="State" class="state">
        <option selected disabled>Choose a State</option>
        <option value="1">California</option>
        <option value="2">New York</option>
      </select> ... Repeated an unknown number of times. ...
      <br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="calculate">
</form>
<textarea id="data"></textarea>
<script>
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var data = $("form").serialize()

    $("#data").val(data);
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

You can also use `serializeArray` which will give you an array of all the values in your form.

```
var postData =$('form').serialize();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <div class="summary">
    <div class="trip">
      <input name="city" value="Some City" type="text" />
      <select name="State" class="state">
        <option selected disabled>Choose a State</option>
        <option value="1">California</option>
        <option value="2">New York</option>
      </select>
      <select name="State" class="state">
        <option selected disabled>Choose a State</option>
        <option value="1">California</option>
        <option value="2">New York</option>
      </select> ... Repeated an unknown number of times. ...
      <br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="calculate">
</form>
<textarea id="data"></textarea>
<script>
  $("#submit").click(function() {
        var m = {};
        $("form").serializeArray().forEach(function(x, y) {
            if(!m[x.name]) {
               m[x.name] = x.value;
            } else {
              var d = [];
              d.push(m[x.name]);
              d.push(x.value);
              m[x.name]=d;
            }
          
          });


          $("#data").val(JSON.stringify(m));
          return false;
        });
</script>
```

Comment: A Django post (and maybe a regular one too) will produce {"State: [u'California', u'New York']}. Is it possible to produce array like this?

Comment: First example shows what a regular post looks like. The server recieving will actually put combine duplicate name values in single comma separated string. There a few different examples on you can serialize the JSON data using the map function and even full jQuery plugins but they all serialize a little differently and likewise everyone wants their JSON serialized in a somewhat different form so I would test a few of them and see which ones give you the format you want.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask why you return false at the end of the submit?

Comment: I updated the JSON to map it like you where looking for but you'll most likely come across something else you want mapped a different way. Return false stops the form from submitting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

Change type of your button to 'submit'.

Handle the submit event of the form and serialize the form data.

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="calculate">

$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
});
```